# SAPUI5 control metadata, adding custom attributes

Tags: sapui5

I am working on adding some common functionality to a potentially large set of diverse custom controls.

To surface my configuration-driven functionality, I was thinking an elegant way could be to add custom members to the "metadata" section of a control's definition.

For example, something like this:

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("myCompany.foo.FooControl", {
    metadata: {
        // normal stuff, properties, aggregation, etc...
        properties: {
        },
        ...

        // my custom stuff
        custom: {
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a best practice way of adding custom content to the metadata object? 
Or, is there a way to get a hold of this object literal at runtime so I could at least parse it for my custom attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe you can add you own kind of metadata to a managed object the values look fixed

```
sap.ui.base.ManagedObjectMetadata.Kind = {
  PROPERTY :0, SINGLE_AGGREGATION : 1, MULTIPLE_AGGREGATION : 2,
  SINGLE_ASSOCIATION : 3, MULTIPLE_ASSOCIATION : 4, EVENT : 5
};
```

to access the metadata of an object you can use the getter getMetadata -eg

```
myControl.getMetadata();
```